# Exceptions limited information in compiled C# applications

Tags: c#

When I debug an application in C# and an exception happens, the Exception object contains a lot of information. For instance: the class and method that caused the exception. I log this information to a log file.

When I built/compile an application, I get very little information in my log file. Something like "Property does not exist", without any information about which class, method or property caused the exception.

How can I change that?

Comment: could you provide us with the code where you are catching and logging the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Steven's answer, note that stack trace information will be "truncated" if you're creating a Release build, as opposed to a Debug build. That is, Debug builds include line numbers and so forth, but Release builds won't.

Comment: I think you can get over this limitation if you include the PDB file, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Building the application does provide an PDB file, this file gives more information about exceptions, like Steven Sudit pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you logging with `ex.ToString()` or just `ex.Message`? You want the former.